# Closed form of a summation involving the product of two factorial functions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation-method

The summation to be evaluated is $$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k-1} \frac{k}{^{3n}C_k} \cdotp$$

I expanded the denominator (using ${^{3n}C_k}=\frac{3n!}{k!({3n-k})!}$) and took $3n!$ outside the summation and I obtained this expression

$$\frac{1}{3n!} \sum_{k=0}^{3n-1} (-1)^{k-1}k!(3n-k)!k.$$

I thought this summation can be solved using the method of telescoping, but I could not do so.

What is the actual procedure to evaluate this summation?

> **Update**: I used wolfram alpha to compute the above summation and saw that the solution is complicated
>   $$
>     \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1} k}{\binom{3n}{k}}
>   = \frac{(3n+1) \binom{3n}{n+1} - 2 (-1)^n n (3 n^2 + 5n + 1)}
>          {3 (n+1) (3n+2) \binom{3n}{n+1}} \cdotp
> $$

However, even with the solution being at hand, I am no closer to solving this misleadingly simple looking sum on pen and paper yet.

Comment: You might be able to use this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: I think you meant the summation should be from k=0 upto n and not r=0 upto n.How did you reach the second expression

Comment: @Navin I have corrected it now. Thanks for pointing that out.